# Openlayers 3 using debugger inside pointermove handler crashes chrome

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, openlayers-3

When I set a breakpoint inside a  " map.on('pointermove', handler) " handler, using chrome's built in debugger, chrome crashes.

By crash, I mean no future pointermove events are generated, and the pointer styles do not react to any elements of the web page (ex. 'cursor' style over links). Drag navigation stops working.

Is this just something I should avoid doing?

Comment: A browser restart is required to make the pointer behave "normally" again

Comment: May it be possible, that the browser stops execution at the breakpoint? Perhaps it still throws mouse events which are all catched by the breakpoint.

Comment: @Peter, yes, the browser debugger breakpoint is caught correctly, and I can step through once.  After or duing that, the pointer symptoms I described begin

Comment: That's because you breakpoint will *not* be deleted automatically. The next time an event occured it is also catch in the breakpoint. I assume at least. ;-) And so no event take effect untill you reload the page (??) or restart the browser. I think the breakpoint is deleted then.

Comment: Give it a try. Set the breakpoint. Move the mouse. When the execution will stop at the breakpoint, delete the breakpoint and do your debugging. Is the problem still there after debugging?

Comment: @Peter, removing the breakpoint while debugging did prevent the crash. Letting it run more than a couple times in a row causes this crash I guess.  I am not sure if this is a chrome issue or a javascript issue, but this is a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is neither an error of the browser nor an error of the interpreter (JS). It's expected behaviour.

If you set a breakpoint in an event handler then execution of the handler code is stopped at the breakpoint, i.e. the event is not excuted until you step on with the debugger or resume execution.

**Edit**

The event handler is running in the event loop thread that performs all event handler of a browser window. If a handler is stopped then, the event loop is paused. But the browser window casts new events if you move the mouse over it for example and then stores them into the event queue. If you resume execution, the next event in the queue will be handled. But the breakpoint is still active. You can resume again but meanwhile there are more and more events stored in the queue. And the next is catched in the breakpoint.

So removing the breakpoint and resume execution is the only thing that could get you out of this trap. Then all events are executed and further events have a chance to be handled too.

I don't know the size of the queue, but if it is full and more events are delivered, the browser could crash. That means the tab/window or the browser itselve will not react anymore.